# Read file from oracleDB and add/delete/modify data

Tags: c#, oracle, file

I'm not very familiar how to do this in C#. Need to connect to Oracle db, take a file from directory then read every line of the file. Lines are like this:

Then will split as string and according to this flag |A|, |D| or |M| I will add/delete/modify information inside.
I don't want to write me whole code. Just some idea and guidelines how to do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**first [read file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/dd383503.aspx) :**

```
var lines  = File.ReadLines(@"filename");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Then split each line
    var str = line.Split('|');  // str contains list of splitted string

    // then save it to db
   using ( var c = new OracleConnection("connectionString") )
   {
      c.Open();
     // check flag
     if ( str [2] == 'A' ) 
     {
      // prepare your sql with splitted array
      var command = c.CreateCommand();
      command.Text = "INSERT INTO table(column) values(:col1)";
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("col1", str[0])
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you and how can i check for what is the parameter/flag?

Comment: Edited but then this code could be written much more better. This will  just  give you a starting point

Answer (score 0):

A [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) may help you...

```
MERGE INTO target_table T
USING source_table S
ON (D.id = S.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
     T.field1 = S.field1,
     T.field2 = S.field2
  DELETE WHERE (S.flag='D')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, field1, filed2)
  VALUES (S.id, S.filed1, S.filed2)
  WHERE S.flag='A';
```

But this will not insert when the record already exists in target.